# Populate nested model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I got this mongoose schema

```js
    const UserSchema = new Schema({
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      groups: [
        {
          groupName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          groupMembers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "GroupMember" }],
        },
      ],
    });
```

I am trying to populate the groupMembers

```js
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId).populate({
          path: "groups",
          populate: {
            path: "groupMembers",
          },
        });
```

When I am logging the 'user', the `groupMembers` array is not populated, it's empty(even though I have objects inside).

Edit: found the solution- the problem was that when I added new `GroupMember` I did'nt `.save()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId).populate('groups.groupMembers');
```

Comment: I tried it, still get the same result (empty groupMembers array).

Comment: You should double check if you really have items in `groups.groupMembers` , because it would be empty array only if it does not have items.

Comment: Yes, I have items in `groups.groupMembers` , I can see the items in my mongo data base, it's an array of `ObjectId`.